# What is the best way to ask user to input a spontaneous content under jQuery Mobile?

Tags: jquery-mobile, cordova

Imagine a list of DVDs for example where user can add more titles as he pleases. Ideally he clicks on a 'plus' button and a little tiny dialog box pops out where he can type in a title of his next movie to be added. Bit like what javascript `prompt();` does. The `prompt()` is good but I'm not too kin on how it says *'http://www.example.com/ says:'* when run in mobile browser (by the way will that show when deployed as a native PhoneGap app?).

My question is what is the best practice to ask user for this type of spontaneous content in mobile apps? **jQueryMobile**, **PhoneGap**

Comment: Have you looked at jQueryMobile Dialogs?  http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/pages/page-dialogs.html  They may not be applicable but they could serve as a starting point

Comment: I found something even better: [SimpleDialog2](http://dev.jtsage.com/jQM-SimpleDialog/demos2/index.html) but am still after something even simpler. At the moment I'm trying to recreate and tailor to my needs search box from IMDB app. Think that is very elegant way to ask users for input.

Comment: Close to what Steve suggests, have a look at the [future popups](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/pages/popup/index.html) in JQM 1.2, especially the form one. If you want something right now though I would just advise you to use a normal JQM dialog window with your own form edits inside.